# How do I dissolve all subfolders

Tags: command-line, directory, find, mv

Is there a command line one-liner to move all the contents of all the direct subfolders of a folder to the folder itself and deleting the subfolders (which are now empty)? I.e., eliminate a level in the folder hierarchy?

To be absolutely clear, the deeper subfolder structure should be preserved.

I've run into this a couple of times now, and I was a little disappointed this doesn't seem to be a feature of Dolphin, nor something other people are struggling with.

I suspect this may have to be split in two, moving the contents of the subfolders, and deleting the subfolders. However, this may have the undesired side-effect of deleting empty second-level sub-folders.

Comment: how would you like to handle the case when two sub-folders in level2 have the same name?

Comment: Yes, it's in two parts, move them, and then delete the (now empty) subdirectories: `rmdir folder/*/` `rmdir` will complain about non-empty directories, so no harm will be done by it.

Comment: @Yaron However move conflicts are normally handled on the command line. Ideally when this occurs the user should get prompted whether they want to skip the sub-sub-folder (and thus also the relevant sub-folder), whether they want to overwrite the existing folder or whether they want to write into it.

Comment: @muru this is not a duplicate ! The pseudo duplicate answer moves all subfiles (whatever the depth) in the current folder. This not what OP asked, OP needs to preserve directory structure.

Comment: @RoVo Thanks! If you turn that into an answer I can accept it. Two things though: 1) a problem I didn't think of, see edit 2) why do you move files and folders separately?

Comment: I thought it may cause problems, but it won't. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually not a real one-liner:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -print -exec mv --backup=numbered -t . '{}' + \
&& find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
```

First find everything in the subfolder with exact depth 2 and move it to `.`. Then find and delete all empty folders in the current directory.

- if you have files/folders with the same name they will be renamed with `original_filename.~n~` (n meaning 1, 2, 3 ...).
- Note that will delete all empty subfolders.

---

**Update:**

I'm not happy with the solution above. Too many caveats and problems. For example when --backup=numbered renames the parent folder of your folder you want to move ...

```
mkdir -p test/test
mv test/test . --backup=numbered
mv: cannot move 'test/test' to './test': No such file or directory
```

Better use a temporary directory to avoid problems. The temp dir should be on the same file system to avoid the need to copy the files.

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -print -exec mv -b -t $tmpdir '{}' +
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
mv -b $tmpdir/* .
rm $tmpdir
```

Comment: There is a small caveat that this will also delete empty second-level subfolders.

Comment: What do you mean by `~n~`?

Comment: No, it will just delete empty folders in "." See the -mindepth/-maxdepth.

Comment: `--exec mv --backup=numbered -t . {} +` so that `find` batches the `mv` command calls.

Comment: @RoVo yes but once those empty second-level subfolders have been moved to `.`, won't they be swooped up by the second statement, that deletes all empty sub-folders?

Answer (score 1):

To guard against deleting empty subdirectories, IMO the simplest way is to move to a temporary directory and then rename the temporary directory to the old one. Say the directory in question is `foo`, and you want `foo/*/*` to become `foo/*`. Do something like:

```
tar c --remove-files foo | tar xv --strip-components=2 --backup=t --one-top-level=temp
mv temp foo
```

- With `--remove-files`, the first `tar` will delete the files as it processes them, finally deleting `foo` itself.
- With `--strip-components=2`, the second `tar` will chop off the `foo/*/` from paths it is extracting, so `foo/a/b` will become `b`.
- `--backup=t` is the same as with `cp` or `mv` - make numbered backup copies. However, `mv` makes copies of directories if they have the same name, but `tar` will merge the directories and make backups of files.
- `--one-top-level=temp` tells `tar` to create a directory named `temp` and extract files there.

For example:

```
$ tree bar
bar
├── a
│   ├── c
│   │   └── bar
│   ├── d
│   │   └── bar
│   ├── e
│   │   └── bar
│   └── f
│       └── bar
├── b
│   ├── c
│   │   └── bar
│   ├── d
│   │   └── bar
│   ├── e
│   │   └── bar
│   └── f
│       └── bar
└── c
    ├── c
    │   └── bar
    ├── d
    │   └── bar
    ├── e
    │   └── bar
    └── f
        └── bar
```

And after running the `tar` commands:

```
$ tar c --remove-files bar | tar xv --strip-components=2 --backup=t --one-top-level=temp
bar/a/e/
bar/a/e/bar
bar/a/f/
bar/a/f/bar
bar/a/c/
bar/a/c/bar
bar/a/d/
bar/a/d/bar
bar/b/e/
bar/b/e/bar
Renaming ‘temp/e/bar’ to ‘temp/e/bar.~1~’
bar/b/f/
bar/b/f/bar
Renaming ‘temp/f/bar’ to ‘temp/f/bar.~1~’
bar/b/c/
bar/b/c/bar
Renaming ‘temp/c/bar’ to ‘temp/c/bar.~1~’
bar/b/d/
bar/b/d/bar
Renaming ‘temp/d/bar’ to ‘temp/d/bar.~1~’
bar/c/e/
bar/c/e/bar
Renaming ‘temp/e/bar’ to ‘temp/e/bar.~2~’
bar/c/f/
bar/c/f/bar
Renaming ‘temp/f/bar’ to ‘temp/f/bar.~2~’
bar/c/c/
bar/c/c/bar
Renaming ‘temp/c/bar’ to ‘temp/c/bar.~2~’
bar/c/d/
bar/c/d/bar
Renaming ‘temp/d/bar’ to ‘temp/d/bar.~2~’

$ tree temp
temp
├── c
│   ├── bar
│   ├── bar.~1~
│   └── bar.~2~
├── d
│   ├── bar
│   ├── bar.~1~
│   └── bar.~2~
├── e
│   ├── bar
│   ├── bar.~1~
│   └── bar.~2~
└── f
    ├── bar
    ├── bar.~1~
    └── bar.~2~

4 directories, 12 files
```

With the `tar` output, you can see when `tar` renamed files for backing up, allowing you track which files became which backups.

---

I'm mildly surprised that it works, but you can actually provide the same directory name for `--one-top-level` and eliminate need to rename. Just this pipeline is enough:

```
tar c --remove-files bar | tar xv --strip-components=2 --backup=t --one-top-level=bar
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mv */* . && rmdir *
```

Move everything in subdirectories into the current directories. rmdir won't delete directories unless they're empty so the second part only deletes empty directories.